# Gaming Keyboard with onboard memory

Tags: gaming, keyboards

I'm looking for a gaming keyboard that has onboard memory for macros, lighting, and profiles.  I've got the Razor Blackwidow Chroma V2 and I love it, but it lacks the onboard memory part.  I can program the macro buttons, but if I move the keyboard to another device, I lose the macros.  I'm not overly picky about the switch types.

Comment: In my experience most high end gaming keyboards have macro support. Also, it would help us a lot more if you could tell us your budget!

Comment: Budget really isn't a concern.  Most top of the line keyboards don't go over $200.  So let's say $200.